# socket.io-client Jest testing inconsistent results

Tags: sockets, socket.io, jestjs

I am writing some end-to-end test cases to test socket connections in my app. I expect receiving socket events after specific rest API requests. For instance, after hitting: `/api/v1/[createTag]`, I expect receiving `createTag` event to be captured by socket.io-client. The issue is that, it is very inconsistently passing, and sometimes failing, with good rest API requests. The reason to fail is that done() event inside `socket.on('createTag' ...` is never called, so it gets timeout. On browser, currently all the API endpoints and sockets seem to be working fine. Is there a specific configuration that I might be missing in order to test socket.io-client within Node.js environment and Jest?

Below is my test cases, and thanks a lot in advance:

```
describe('Socket integration tests: ', () => {

  beforeAll(async done => {

    await apiInit();

    const result = await requests.userSignIn(TEST_MAIL, TEST_PASSWORD);

    TEST_USER = result.user;
    SESSION = result.user.session;

    console.log('Test user authenticated succesfully.');

    done();

  });

  beforeEach(done => {

    socket = io(config.socket_host, { forceNew: true })

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket connection succesful.');

      socket.emit('session', { data: SESSION }, (r) => {
        console.log('Socket session successful.');
        done();
      });

    });

  })

  test('Receiving createTag socket event?', async(done) => {

    console.log('API request on createTag');
    const response = await Requester.post(...);
    console.log('API response on createTag', response);

    socket.on('createTag', result => {

      console.log('createTag socket event succesful.');
      createdTagXid = result.data.xid;

      done();

    })

  });

  afterEach(done => {

    if(socket.connected) {
      console.log('disconnecting.');
      socket.disconnect();
    } else {
      console.log('no connection to break');
    }

    done();

  })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, setting event handles after async API calls seems to be the issue. So I should have first set the `socket.on( ...` and then call rest API.

Comment: This was my issue too